# Dimension intersection two manifolds

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, geometry, manifolds, smooth-functions

let $X$ and $Y$ be two $(n-1)$ dimensional manifolds in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of class $C^1$ and $C^\infty$ respectively, and denotes by $\mu^{(1)}$ and $\mu^{(2)}$ the two outer unit normal vectors to $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

**Question**: is true that 
$$\mathcal{H}^{n-1} \left\{ z \in X \cap Y: \mu^{(1)}(z)=\mu^{(2)}(z)\right\} =0 $$

Thanks.

Comment: Think about the case $X = Y$...

Comment: Mmm can you explain levap? In my case in particular $Y=\left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n: x_n=c \right\}$, $x_n$ the $n-$th component and $c$ a fixed constant.

Comment: @Papermax89: I mean, the way you stated the question allows you to take $X = Y$ and then $\{ z \in X \cap Y \, | \, \mu^{(1)}(z) = \mu^{(2)}(z) \} = X = Y$ which clearly has non-zero $n-1$ dimensional measure... On the other hand, $\{ z \in X \cap Y \, | \, \mu^{(1)}(z) \neq \pm \mu^{(2)}(z) \}$ has zero measure as it is locally $n-2$-dimensional

Comment: Sorry levap, I meant $X \neq Y$. For $Y$ as above what can I say about the dimension $\left\{ z \in X \cap Y: \mu^{(1)}(z)=\mu^{(2)}(z)\right\}$?

Comment: Nothing interesting... $Y$ might still be an open subset of $X$ and then the intersection will be $n - 1$-dimensional or they might intersect transversely and then it will be $n-2$-dimensional and it can also be "mixed".